# Preventing Rails from adding time stamp field to the model and schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

When  I use Rails generator to generate a Model, it automatically adds that timestamp field which also causes those two time stamp fields in the schema to be created.

I know I can write a migration to remove those two fields but I was wondering if there is a way to actually not generate them to begin with, instead of creating a migration to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line in the your terminal to get the help options for the specific generator (model) in this case.

```
rails g model --help
```

The option you want to use to prevent the addition of the fields (`created_at` and `updated_at`) is as follows:

```
rails g model <model_name> <[[field_name(fn):field_type(ft)], [fn:ft]]> --timestamps=false
```

The corresponding migration created with this will not have the two timestamp fields.

Example:

```
rails g model test --timestamps=false

  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130225224757_create_tests.rb
  create    app/models/test.rb
```

The output of checking the file with the unix `cat` command to view the file confirms that the timestamps are not included in the migration.

```
cat db/migrate/*_create_tests.rb
class CreateTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tests do |t|
    end
  end
end
```